# NGINX Handling redirects returned from the upstream

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I want to proxy requests and do it to the different domains. URI in `proxy_pass` depends on `link` query parameter from the request. Here is what I tried in my nginx configuration:

```
location ~* /proxy?(.*) {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            set $link $arg_link;
            set $args '';
            if ($link !~* "http") {
               rewrite ^ / break;
               proxy_pass http://$link;
            }
            rewrite ^ / break;
            proxy_pass $link;
    }
```

I'm not sure that it's the best way to resolve my issue, nevertheless it almost works correct, but instead of proxy I'm getting redirect. I don't need to get 302 status code and redirect, because in this case I have issues with CORS.

Request example: `http://localhost/proxy?link=www.google.com`

Answer (score 1):

After many hours I finally found a solution that works for me.

```
    location ~ /proxy/(.*) {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        set $link $arg_link;
        set $args '';
        if ($link !~* "http") {
            set $link http://$link;
        }

        rewrite ^ / break;
        proxy_pass $link;
        recursive_error_pages on;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirect;
    }
```

And one more location to handle redirects:

```
   location @handle_redirect {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirect;
        set $saved_redirect_location $upstream_http_location;
        proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;
    }
```

Comment: Really, very nice solution! Unfortunately the question title is loosely related to its content and makes it hard to find. You'd better rename your question to something like "Handling redirects returned from the upstream".